# User defined loss function in LSTM model in Python

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have referred a univariate LSTM model which is shown here: https://github.com/krishnaik06/Time-Series-Forecasting/blob/master/UnivariateTimeSeries.ipynb

**The codes for the univariate LSTM model are as such:**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# preparing independent and dependent features
def prepare_data(timeseries_data, n_features):
    X, y =[],[]
    for i in range(len(timeseries_data)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_features
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(timeseries_data)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = timeseries_data[i:end_ix], timeseries_data[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)


# define input sequence
timeseries_data = [110, 125, 133, 146, 158, 172, 187, 196, 210]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 3
# split into samples
X, y = prepare_data(timeseries_data, n_steps)


print("\n X = \n",X)
print("\n y = \n",y)
print("\n")
    
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))


# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=300, verbose=1)


# demonstrate prediction for next 10 days
x_input = np.array([187, 196, 210])
temp_input=list(x_input)
lst_output=[]
i=0
while(i<10):
    
    if(len(temp_input)>3):
        x_input=np.array(temp_input[1:])
        print("{} day input {}".format(i,x_input))
        #print(x_input)
        x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
        #print(x_input)
        yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
        print("{} day output {}".format(i,yhat))
        temp_input.append(yhat[0][0])
        temp_input=temp_input[1:]
        #print(temp_input)
        lst_output.append(yhat[0][0])
        i=i+1
    else:
        x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
        yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
        print(yhat[0])
        temp_input.append(yhat[0][0])
        lst_output.append(yhat[0][0])
        i=i+1
    print("\n")
        

print("\n lst_output = \n",lst_output)


# Plot the prediction for next 10 days
day_new=np.arange(1,10)
day_pred=np.arange(10,20)
plt.plot(day_new,timeseries_data)
plt.plot(day_pred,lst_output)
plt.show()
```

Here, the  **model loss** is mean sqaured error (**mse**).

However, I wish to make use of **scoring function** as given here: https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1702/6/3/35

[image]

**The scoring function codes are as scuh:**

```
import numpy as np

## Maximize Score function. This should be close to 1
## Hence the loss function should be to minimize the (1/Score function)
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            
    Error     = (y_true - y_pred)/y_true
    Per_Error = 100*Error
    Score_units = np.empty((np.int64(np.shape(Per_Error)[0]),0))   ## Empty array 


    for i in range (0,np.shape(Per_Error)[0]) :

        #print("\n Per_Error[{}] = {}\n ".format(i, Per_Error[i]))

        if Per_Error[i] <= 0 :
            Score_ith_unit = np.exp( (-1) * np.log(0.5)  * Per_Error[i]/5)
            #print("\n Score_ith_unit = {}\n ".format(Score_ith_unit))
            Score_units = np.append(Score_units, Score_ith_unit)
            #print("\n Score_units = \n ",Score_units)
            
            
        if Per_Error[i] > 0 :
            Score_ith_unit = np.exp( (+1) * np.log(0.5)  * Per_Error[i]/20)
            #print("\n Score_ith_unit = {}\n ".format(Score_ith_unit))
            Score_units = np.append(Score_units, Score_ith_unit)
            #print("\n Score_units = \n ",Score_units)

    print("\n Score_units = \n ", Score_units)
    print("\n np.mean(Score_units) = \n ", np.mean(Score_units))          ## Score function needs to be maximized (Close to 1)
    print("\n 1/(np.mean(Score_units)) = \n ", 1/(np.mean(Score_units)))  ## Loss function needs to be minimized 

    return 1/(np.mean(Score_units)) # Loss function

## Test the above codes for some arbitrary arrays
Y_true = np.array([15, 20, 30, 25, 16])   # Some arbitrary array
Y_pred = np.array([50, 8, 45, 20, 24])   # Some arbitrary array
custom_loss(Y_true, Y_pred)   # Check the score and loss function
```

Now I need to **integrate the custom loss function into univariate LSTM**. The complete codes reads as scuh:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# preparing independent and dependent features
def prepare_data(timeseries_data, n_features):
    X, y =[],[]
    for i in range(len(timeseries_data)):
            # find the end of this pattern
            end_ix = i + n_features
            # check if we are beyond the sequence
            if end_ix > len(timeseries_data)-1:
                    break
            # gather input and output parts of the pattern
            seq_x, seq_y = timeseries_data[i:end_ix], timeseries_data[end_ix]
            X.append(seq_x)
            y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)


# define input sequence
timeseries_data = [110, 125, 133, 146, 158, 172, 187, 196, 210]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 3
# split into samples
X, y = prepare_data(timeseries_data, n_steps)


print("\n X = \n",X)
print("\n y = \n",y)
print("\n")
    
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))


## Maximize Score function. This should be close to 1
## Hence the loss function should be to minimize the (1/Score function)
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            
    Error     = (float(y_true) - float(y_pred))/float(y_true)
    Per_Error = 100*Error
    Score_units = np.empty((np.int64(np.shape(Per_Error)[0]),0))   ## Empty array 


    for i in range (0,np.shape(Per_Error)[0]) :

        #print("\n Per_Error[{}] = {}\n ".format(i, Per_Error[i]))

        if Per_Error[i] <= 0 :
            Score_ith_unit = np.exp( (-1) * np.log(0.5)  * Per_Error[i]/5)
            #print("\n Score_ith_unit = {}\n ".format(Score_ith_unit))
            Score_units = np.append(Score_units, Score_ith_unit)
            #print("\n Score_units = \n ",Score_units)
            
            
        if Per_Error[i] > 0 :
            Score_ith_unit = np.exp( (+1) * np.log(0.5)  * Per_Error[i]/20)
            #print("\n Score_ith_unit = {}\n ".format(Score_ith_unit))
            Score_units = np.append(Score_units, Score_ith_unit)
            #print("\n Score_units = \n ",Score_units)

    print("\n Score_units = \n ", Score_units)
    print("\n np.mean(Score_units) = \n ", np.mean(Score_units))          ## Score function needs to be maximized (Close to 1)
    print("\n 1/(np.mean(Score_units)) = \n ", 1/(np.mean(Score_units)))  ## Loss function needs to be minimized 

    return 1/(np.mean(Score_units)) # Loss function



# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
##model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss)


# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=300, verbose=1)


# demonstrate prediction for next 10 days
x_input = np.array([187, 196, 210])
temp_input=list(x_input)
lst_output=[]
i=0
while(i<10):
    
    if(len(temp_input)>3):
        x_input=np.array(temp_input[1:])
        print("{} day input {}".format(i,x_input))
        #print(x_input)
        x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
        #print(x_input)
        yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
        print("{} day output {}".format(i,yhat))
        temp_input.append(yhat[0][0])
        temp_input=temp_input[1:]
        #print(temp_input)
        lst_output.append(yhat[0][0])
        i=i+1
    else:
        x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
        yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
        print(yhat[0])
        temp_input.append(yhat[0][0])
        lst_output.append(yhat[0][0])
        i=i+1
    print("\n")
        

print("\n lst_output = \n",lst_output)


# Plot the prediction for next 10 days
day_new=np.arange(1,10)
day_pred=np.arange(10,20)
plt.plot(day_new,timeseries_data)
plt.plot(day_pred,lst_output)
plt.show()
```

**Edit-1:**

After the suugestions given by @Dr.Snoopy, I changed the 'Error' formulation to float. However I get e new error for 'Score_units' as such:

Score_units = np.empty((np.int64(np.shape(Per_Error)[0]),0))   ## Empty array

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Can somebody please let me know why does this happen and how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: your y_true is an integer while a float is expected, just cast it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dr.Snoopy ...I implemented your suggestions as mentioned in Edit-1 of my post. However, now I am getting a new error 'Score_units'. Could you please let me know how can we solve this issue.

Comment: The other issue is that you cannot use numpy inside a custom loss or metric,  you need to use tensorflow functions, and basically complete rewrite the metric.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dr.Snoopy for your feedback....I dont have much idea about tensorflow. Could you please suggest some study material/wesites from where I can start learning tensorflow